# function in .profile to move a folder from location A to current working directory

Tags: bash, command-line, terminal

I have folder called Demo on my desktop. The following line moves the default folder to the Demo folder.

```
mv /Users/me/Documents/Work/Projects/default Demo/
```

But I need to have the following:
in my .profile, I would like to have a function that moves the default folder's children (sub-folders and files) to the directory I'm currently in (cfr. Demo).

So I could do this in the Demo-folder:
generate-default-folder-structure (function name from .profile-file)

Could anyone help me out with this one, please?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood you correctly, this should work:

```
mv ~me/Documents/Work/Projects/default/* .
```

It will move all (non-hidden, typically) contents of that `default` directory to your current directory.